# Security when either side can start a connection

Tags: linux, windows, security, encryption, kerberos

What is a good way to provide security (encryption & authentication) between systems where either side can initiate the connection?

In my situation there is one master system and many child systems. The child systems initiate connections to the master so they can report data, and the master initiates connections with the children to issue commands. Currently we achieve security through kerberos on windows, but we are introducing linux children who aren't connected to the Active Directory, so kerberos will no longer be an option.

Is there a way to do this without each computer in the tree having it's own private/public key pair? That seems like it would be a mess to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best bet is to use SASL for two reaons:

1. You have a stateful bi-directional connetion between client and server
2. You are free to choose an authentication mechanism. If you can use Kerberos, you can fully encrypt the entire traffic. If not, you still can use STARTTLS with PKI.

Comment: I'm looking at the sasl documentation, and it looks like it has to be used with a registered service. Is this true? Our protocol is proprietary.

Comment: No, you can use SASL as you think fit. Best examples are LDAP, SMTP, IMAP, etc.